# Evaluate: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Evaluate: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n}}dx$$

Comment: You're not new here -- you ought to know how to abide by the website policy when asking a question.

Comment: This is the famous "*you have to get a $\sqrt{\pi}$ out of something*", for instance through the Laplace/Hayman methods (for short, you may replace the integrand function by $e^{-nx^2}$ and the integration range by $\mathbb{R}^+$, the outcome is unaffected).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substituting $x=u/\sqrt{n}$,

$$ \sqrt{n} \int_{0}^{1} (1 + x^2)^{-n} \, dx
= \int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \left( 1 + \frac{u^2}{n} \right)^{-n} \, du
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \, du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}. $$

The convergence is justified by noting that the integrand $\frac{1}{(1+u^2/n)^n}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(u)$ is dominated by the integrable function $\frac{1}{1+u^2} $ and converges pointwise to $e^{-u^2}$.