# A limit integral inequality

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, approximation, maxima-minima

Consider $$ L = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt n\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}dx$$

Given is that $$L < 1/2$$

What is the minimum upper bound on L.

What have i tried :

1. Generating a recurrence relation for the involved integral : I however could not find a proper line of reasoning to calculate the minimum upper bound.
2. Finding the value of integral involved for n= 1, 2, 3... and guess a pattern for n. The value for n=1 , 2 , 3 however does not offer an easily observable pattern.
   .
   It finally struck me that if i change the denominator of the involved integral from $1+x^2$ to $x^2$ I can argue as follows
   $$\sqrt n\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}dx < \sqrt n \int_{0}^1  \frac{1}{x^{2n}}dx$$
   This however did not help me as the integral on the RHS could not be evaluated at the lower limit.I then replaced $(1+ x^2)$ by $(1+x)^2$ As this will also ensure the following:
   $$\sqrt n \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}dx < \sqrt n \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^{2n}}dx$$ The RHS integral had the value : $$\sqrt n\frac{1}{-2n+1}(\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}-1)$$
   Imposing the limit n goes to infinity on this gives $0$ which is certainly not what I expected.
   .
   What am i missing here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt n \int_0^1 \frac{\,dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984468/finding-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-n-int-01-frac-dx1x2n) **and** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992229/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-int-01-frac11x2ndx?noredirect=1&lq=1 **and** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998545/l-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-int-01-fracdx1x2n?noredirect=1&lq=1 **and** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185988/how-to-find-the-limit-of?noredirect=1&lq=1